# JSON Dump in Python CGI starts with trailing dots

Tags: python, json, cgi

The data returned from run_report returns a python dictionary, where it is then parsed into JSON String and printed so it can be accessed by JSON. The run_report function also creates a .json file in which I can access later:

```
print "Content-type: application/json\n"
json_data = run_report(sites_list, tierOne, dateFrom, dateTo, filename, file_extension)
print json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

However, when it prints, I receive this output:

```
..{
"data": {
    "FR": 1424068
}, 
"tierone": {
    "countries": [
        "US", 
        "BR", 
        ...
    ], 
    "ratio": 100.0, 
    "total": 1424068, 
    "total_countries": 1
}, 
"total": 1424068, 
"total_countries": 1
}
```

What I don't understand is how those trailing dots even show up. The dots, however, do not show up if I were to open one of the .json files I created with the run_report function and print the read data file.

```
def open_file(file_extension, json_file):
    with open(file_extension + json_file) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
    return json.dumps(data)

json_data = open_file(file_extension, filename)
    print json_data
```

Comment: The dots are not produced by the Python code you posted. Have you tried printing something *entirely different* and see if those dots are still there?

Comment: And if this is a CGI, are you checking the output in a browser or in a different tool?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm viewing this from the browser. From the Build, it prints out fine. However, now that I'm investigating more, I think this may be the case: heartbeat = lambda: sys.stdout.write('.') - though, I thought this will only present itself in the logs versus the browser

Comment: No, `print` writes to `sys.stdout` too. Use `sys.stderr` instead if you want to direct information to the logs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That was actually it. It was the stdout that printed out the dots. Replaced with stderr, works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something *else* is producing those `.` characters; the `json.dumps()` function never adds those.

Make sure nothing else is writing to `sys.stdout`; everything you send to `sys.stdout` is sent to the browser (`print` writes to `sys.stdout` by default).

From your comments I understand you wanted to write additional information to the server logs; do not use `sys.stdout` for that; write to `sys.stderr` instead.